# How to Exclude sunday in minDate jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar

how to exclude the sundays .....

I have included the page link below...
        [Keith wood datepicker jquery](http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datepick.css">     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // $("#from1").datepick({dateFormat: 'MM dd yyyy'});
        $("#to").datepick({dateFormat: 'MM dd yyyy'});

        $('#from1').datepick({
            minDate: -1, 
            showTrigger: '#calImg', 
            dateFormat: 'MM dd yyyy'}
        );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply exclude Sunday:

```
 $("#.datePicker").datepicker({
     minDate: -1,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       return [date.getDay() == 2] || [date.getDay() == 3] || [date.getDay() == 4] || [date.getDay() == 5] || [date.getDay() == 6] || 
     }
  })
```

Comment: Why not just: `return [date.getDay() !== 1]`?

Comment: Good idea, hadn't thought of that.